# Translate a FB "action" to French

Tags: translation, facebook-timeline

I've created some FB actions for my application.
But all actions are in english by default ...

I want to publish actions in timeline for french people, so i tried to user the link :
"Translate your app" (right collumn in Apps config page) [http://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/]

But this functionnality doesn't work, i can't find ( French (France), there is only "French (Canada)" ) And if i use French Canada, my test users still have action in english.

So my question is : how to translate my apps ?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have a solution ? It's a huge bug, we can't have a FB apps with new open graph features in France !!!!

Answer (score 0):

French (Canada) is very close to French (France), only a few obscure differences.

If you still get english words by translating to French (Canada), then the translation fails.

Answer (score 0):

French (France) is the option right under French (Canada) in the Translations module, mon ami :)